# How do I stop the Amazon Music for PC manager/downloader creating these unwanted folders?

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

Every so often I would notice that 256 folders called "aa", "ab", ... "ff" would appear in my music folder. Today I realised that it was the Amazon Music for PC manager/downloader app that was creating them. I don't buy that much music from Amazon, but occasionally they do have good deals which is why I'd not noticed before.

The folders get created when I open the app, but it doesn't appear to use them as when I check they are always all empty.

How do I stop it creating these folders?

Comment: Have you checked the app settings to see how you might control these?

Comment: @music I can't see anything that would appear to be related.